# Issue with submitting form when "&" in description box

Tags: php, mysql

This problem has been happening across all my forms. If in a description, a user has the ampersand symbol in there, the page displays the INSERT statement with the values but doesn't proceed or send an email out.

For example:

"The quick brown fox jumps over the dog **&** the cat" will not work.

"The quick brown fox jumps over the dog **and** the cat" will work.

Insert statment on one of the pages:

```
$filename = $_GET['filename'];
$size = $_GET['filesize'];
$date = $_GET['filedate'];
$user = $loggedin_id;
$desc = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc3, $_GET['desc']);
$type = $_GET['type'];
$ver = $_GET['ver'];
$rev = $_GET['rev'];
$sql = "SELECT lineup FROM cad_files WHERE job_num = $job_id AND file_type = '$type' ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1";
$result = mysqli_query($dbc3, $sql);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) < 1){
    $prev_lineup = 0;
} else {
    $prev_file = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    $prev_lineup = $prev_file['lineup'];
}
//$type = getcadtype($type);
$job_id = getjobid($job_num, $dbc3);
$sql = "INSERT INTO cad_files(job_num, user, file_name, file_type, version, revision, date, size, description) VALUES($job_id, '$user', '$filename', '$type', '$ver', '$rev', '$date', '$size', '$desc')";
// echo $sql;
mysqli_query($dbc3, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($dbc3));

$id = mysqli_insert_id($dbc3);
```

How can I resolve this issue ?

ERRORS:

> Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 9: parser error :
>   xmlParseEntityRef: no name in
>   /home/xxxxx/public_html/main/includes/mail2.php on line 15
>
> Warning: simplexml_load_string(): <p>Description:<br
>   /><b>Inserts 3a & 3b modified</b></p> in
>   /home/xxxxx/public_html/main/includes/mail2.php on line 15
>
> Warning: simplexml_load_string(): ^ in
>   /home/xxxxxx/public_html/main/includes/mail2.php on line 15
>
> Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to simpleXMLToArray() must be
>   an instance of SimpleXMLElement, boolean given, called in
>   /home/xxxxxx/public_html/main/includes/mail2.php on line 15 and
>   defined in /home/xxxxxx/public_html/main/includes/functions.php on
>   line 354

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: ALL the inputs should be secured before inserting into DB. if you want all values in your query: `$_GET = array_map('mysqli_real_escape_string', $_GET)`

Comment: `mysqli_real_escape_string()` use this

Comment: @AwladLiton he does, but not everywhere. it would be much better to use PreparedStatements

Comment: @AwladLiton It is used on description ? $desc = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc3, $_GET['desc']);

Comment: use prepare statement yes that is true ...

Comment: @Martijn I use this after all the $_GETs ? And if you notice, its used already on description $desc = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc3, $_GET['desc']); yet I'm still having problems with ampersand.

Comment: You add the array_map before you assign its values to the variables. Just echo your query and see **why** it faults instead of trying some weird fix :)

Comment: Do you get an error message, if yes, what is it?

Comment: @Adarsh Yes multiple errors when it tries to send the email. I'll edit, refer to original post.

Comment: The interesting thing here is that he gets warning about the use of `simplexml_load_string` which doesn't appear in the code - I think that we didn't get the whole code

Comment: @YaronU. So what do you think the problem is then? I think it has to do with the passed values before it gets to the email portion. That part works if I omit the ampersand...

Comment: @MikeOscarEcho it is quiet hard to see the problem like this - this is the kind of things that you should debug the code in order to get the line of the error - and then get more info.
as others mentioned - you for sure have a SQL injection problem here

Comment: Well I guess you have to show us a bit more of your code... esp. the lines which cause the error / bugs.

Comment: Solved it using  htmlspecialchars() on $desc after escaping. Only issue is that it inserts it into table as "&amp;". I guess this will have to do for now, I will secure the rest of the variables based on everyones recommendation. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Because you are sending everything over the query string (HTTP GET) you should escape your variables before you send them to the server.

Use the javascript `escape` function to encode characters like that.  **You'll need to decode them on the server side as well**.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it using htmlspecialchars() on $desc after escaping.

```
$desc = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc3, $_GET['desc']);
$desc = htmlspecialchars($desc);
```

Only issue is that it inserts it into table as "&" but this isn't really a problem as the page displays the "&" anyway. I guess this will have to do for now, I will secure the rest of the variables based on everyones recommendation.